# Are there any timelapse camera app on Android that takes images instead of videos?

Tags: android, images, camera, timer

I want to take a series of photos at full resolution so that I can manually edit them into a 4K time lapse video later. However all of the apps that are advertised as "time lapse camera" I tried on the Play Store simply output the video file directly. That removes a lot of image information and limits my editing later. Even worse, they only output full HD videos at most. Some do support 4K output after paying, but even then I have no way to do cropping or panning afterward

I once used a time lapse application that stores the image series in a video file with MJPEG codec, but it was incompatible with some later versions of Android. [This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sheado.timelapse) is also capable of capturing MJPEG videos but it was very buggy, and only supports 2048x1536

I also recall using some app that can take pictures **even while the screen is off**, so it consumes very little power, but somehow it doesn't run on my new phones several years ago, and seems like it was removed from the store

I just want an app that takes pictures at periodic interval. Currently I'm using [open camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) but the screen is on all the time so sometimes it gets very hot and hang up completely.

Are there any suggestions for that? A free solution is preferred, but I'm willing to spend some money for a great app that suits my needs.

Comment: I haven't tried that feature, but e.g. [Camera FV-5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flavionet.android.camera.lite) and [Sensor Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wilfredo.bigol.sensorcamera) advertize time-lapse functionality. And I'd also think that some of the [surveillance cameras](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/remotedroid_webcams#group_729) should be capable of that.